# How to pass mail tokens to the admin user settings

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

How could i pass `custom mail tokens` from my `custom module` to the `admin user settings` page.In the `admin user settings` page I see a part like `Welcome, awaiting administrator approval`.In this part it shows the `available variables` are: `!username`, `!site`, `!password`, `!uri`, `!uri_brief`, `!mailto`, `!date`, `!login_uri`, `!edit_uri`, `!login_url`.Is there any way by which i could add my own `custom variables` so that it can be accessed in the corresponding `mail` body..?I need to pass some `variables` from my `custom module` to this `user setings` part.Could some one help me with this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who might be looking for the solution,here is how i solved it.Do check the link  below to see how to `create your own tokens in the user admin settings`.Its was a very quite useful piece of code .Anyways thanks to the uploader.. :)

http://www.innoraft.com/blog/use-profile-fields-tokens-user-emails-drupal